# How can I stop the player leaving the grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a game for my computing class where the player has to move around a grid and collect passengers. I decided to make mine in JavaScript using jQuery and so far I have constructed the grid, added the necessary colours of individual boxes and allowed the player to move.

The issue I am now facing is that I do not know how I can stop the player leaving the grid.
This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>BotMod</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  ul{list-style:none;}
  a{text-decoration:none;}


  #grid{
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }

  .box{
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin:4px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
  }

  #player {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 15px;
  }

</style>

<style id="jsbin-css">

</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="grid">
</div>

<script>
var boxX = 0;
var boxY = 0;
var box = '<div class="box" />';

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
  $('#grid').append(box);
  $('#grid .box:eq(0)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(1)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(2)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(3)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(4)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(5)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(6)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(7)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(8)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(9)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(10)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(11)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(12)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(13)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(14)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(15)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(16)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(17)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(18)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(19)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(20)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(21)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(22)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(23)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(24)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(25)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(26)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(27)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(28)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(29)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(30)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(31)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(32)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(33)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(34)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(35)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(36)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(37)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(38)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(39)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(40)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(41)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(42)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(43)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(44)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(45)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(46)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(47)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(48)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(49)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(50)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(51)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(52)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(53)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(54)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(55)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(56)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(57)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(58)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(59)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(60)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(61)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(62)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(63)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(64)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(65)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(66)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(67)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(68)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(69)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(70)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(71)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(72)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(73)').css('background', '#49311c');
  $('#grid .box:eq(74)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(75)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(76)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(77)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(78)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(79)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(80)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(81)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(82)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(83)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(84)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(85)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(86)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(87)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(88)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(89)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(90)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(91)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(92)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(93)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(94)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(95)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(96)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(97)').css('background', 'green');
  $('#grid .box:eq(98)').css('background', 'white');
  $('#grid .box:eq(99)').css('background', '#49311c');
}

$(function() {
var player = '<div id="player"></div>';
$('#grid .box:eq(0)').append(player);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

var position = $('#player').position();
pLeft = 15;
switch (e.keyCode) {

  case 37: // Left
  $('#player').css('left', position.left - 50 + 'px');
  break;

  case 38: // Up
  $('#player').css('top', position.top - 50 + 'px');
  break;

  case 39: // Right
  $('#player').css('left', position.left + 50 + 'px');
  break;

  case 40: // Down
  $('#player').css('top', position.top + 50 + 'px');
  break;

}

   });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if it is hard to understand what I am trying to say but essentially I need some help stopping the player from leaving the grid. I am still learning JavaScript and jQuery but I wanted to push myself so code examples will be a lot easier for me to understand.

I was thinking of an `If` statement like so:

```
If (pLeft <= 15) {
    pLeft += ...;
}
```

However I can not seem to fathom out how to do it.

EDIT:

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3Rz/

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, it makes it much easier to see what you are working with. With this much code though, providing a working example through jsfiddle is often better than posting the entire code dump here. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3Rz/

Comment: Thanks, edited my question to include that link.

Comment: If you haven't seen my answer yet, you can close the for loop after $('#grid').append(box); , you are setting the cells colors 100 times which is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using @aZen 's tip: 
    I tried to make the make generation map more neat, hope it helps too. Feel free to ask anything you do not understand. Didn't make whole map, but you should get the idea:

```
switch (e.keyCode) {

  case 37: // Left
  $('#player').css('left', Math.max(15, Math.min(9*50 + 15,position.left - 50)) + 'px');  
  break;

  case 38: // Up
  $('#player').css('top', Math.max(15, Math.min(9*50 + 15,position.top - 50)) + 'px');
  break;

   case 39: // Right
  $('#player').css('left', Math.max(15, Math.min(9*50 + 15,position.left + 50)) + 'px');
  break;

  case 40: // Down
  $('#player').css('top', Math.max(15, Math.min(9*50 + 15,position.top + 50)) + 'px');
  break;
```

}

Full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bucQ7/

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. I like how you re-constructed the grid and I sort of understand how math.min and max works so thank you again for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped, have fun with your game!

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement is definitely one possibility, but I think that a better method is to never allow the value to be set off of the grid in the first place. When assigning the position after the player moves left, for example, you set the new position to

```
position.left - 50
```

Instead, it is possible to use the `Math.max` function to set it to either `position.left - 50` or the minimum value you want (in your case, `pLeft`, which is `15`), whichever is larger.

That is, you want to set the position to the return value of the `Math.max` function call. The same logic can be applied for moving up, and very similar logic can be applied on the right and bottom, but with `Math.min` instead.

Comment: Try "case 37: $('#player').css('left', Math.max(15, Math.min(9*50 + 15,position.left - 50)) + 'px'); break;" for "left"
and similar for the other cases.